# How to remove files from installation when used prefix in linux?

Tags: linux, openssl

I was installing openssl library by hand using these commands:

```
wget http://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf openssl-1.0.0.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.0

./config --prefix=/home/<username>/.sys shared
make
make install
```

Now I need to install new version but I need to completely remove files from prefix folders

Can I just remove whole .sys folder or is there any special command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the original source tree will provide you with a make uninstall, assuming someone cared to create that make target.

Whatever you simply can remove your ~/.sys folder or not really depends on what else you might have installed there, or not.

Some people prefer to rather use a --prefix such as /base/path/name/version, keeping it all tidy and separate. The potential downside to that approach is that it makes handling paths a bit trickier; more so when it comes to libraries than when it comes to binaries.